# Compilation error: duplicate class with MapStruct in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using [Mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org/) for mapping between different Java Beans, but after installing the latest IntelliJ update, Compilation is getting failed with error:

```
Compilation error: duplicate class
```

Here are the version details of IntelliJ

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-191.6183.87, built on March 27, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b39 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.3
```

Compilation Error :

```
Error:(14, 8) java: duplicate class: com.company.mapper.GMapperImpl
```

Comment: Please post the full error, you have a duplicated class somewhere.

Comment: Done, Also this was working fine until this update, This mapperImpl class gets autogenerated by mapstruct library, i have checked there is no duplicate class.

Comment: Have you tried to clean/rebuild your project and run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: What does `grep GMapperImpl -R <path/to/project/directory>` print? What are the files that define the duplicated `GMapperImpl` class?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki `.out` directory causing this problem, I deleted it and it started working fine.

Comment: @y.bedrov Why cache invalidation should help? For me it still looks like IntelliJ bug, even if cache invalidation works, but I see yourtrack for this issue has been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.out` directory was causing this problem, I deleted it and it started working fine

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue for my classes and it got resolved by performing `maven clean` from inside `intellij` by clicking on `clean` lifecycle phase on maven project where this error is coming and then build the project again from `intellij`.

[image]

Comment: if anyone still struggling, I had struggle with this for hours, deleted cache, and what not nothing worked, finally deleted generated source directory then started working

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the .java file if it already exists in the original package and if you copied in a previous run and then run and a new copy will be found under the target folder and this will eliminate the duplicate class error.
Even if the error appears it still doesn't hurt since the new class will always be generated under target -> generated-sources->annotation folder. Once you copy this over and delete the copy under target folder you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (a multi module project) it was because the project configuration messed up: in the module configuration (F4) there was a second source root pointing to the master pom. Removing that was enough.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `target` folder and everything working fine.